# how to vectorize this python code to make it more efficient? (in speed)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to vectorize my code using numpy modules, the original code is like:

```
m = [M[i,:9].dot(N[:9,i]) for i in xrange(9)]
```

and I have improved the code as:

```
m = np.diagonal(M[:9,:9].dot(N[:9,:9]))
```

yet this will lead to some unnecessary calculations (especially when the index is much greater than 9). What can I do to improve the efficiency further?

Edit: Basically what I intend to do is to calculate the diagonal elements of the dot product of two matrixes M and N.

Comment: It's always nice to mention what the code is actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have re-edited my question now

Comment: Sorry for the misleading information, but in my practical code the shape of two matrixes are not bound to be square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) as we need to keep the first axis of `M` aligned with the second axis of `N`, while reducing/losing the leftover axes from the inputs. Thus, we would have an `einsum` based solution, like so:

```
m = np.einsum('ij,ji->i',M[:,:9],N[:9,:])
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it indeed improves the numerical efficiency a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that both matrices are square and have the same dimensions, this is what we can do:

1. By the definition of matrix multiplication, the result you want to calculate is basically a vector of dot products. The first element of the result vector is the dot product of M's first row with N's first column, followed by the dot product of M's second row with N's second column, etc.
2. We can express this calculation by transposing N, then multiplying M and N<sup>T</sup> element-wise, then adding up each row. This gives us a resulting column vector. This is the code:

   ```
   Nprime = np.transpose(N[:,:9])
   product = np.multiply(M[:9,:], Nprime)
   result = np.sum(product, axis=1)
   ```

   By Divakar's suggestion, it can be condensed into one line:

   ```
   result = (M[:,:9] * (N[:9,:].T)).sum(1)
   ```

---

Example (with size 3 instead of 9):

```
import numpy as np

>>> M = np.array(
    [[1, 2, 3],
     [6, 5, 4],
     [8, 7, 9]])

>>> N = np.array(
    [[0, 9, 7],
     [2, 4, 5],
     [6, 8, 1]])

>>> M.dot(N)
array([[22,  41,  20],
       [34, 106,  71],
       [68, 172, 100]])

>>> np.diagonal(M.dot(N))
array([22, 106, 100])
# ^ The reference answer

>>> Nprime = np.transpose(N)
array([[0, 2, 6],
       [9, 4, 8],
       [7, 5, 1]])

>>> product = np.multiply(M, Nprime)
array([[ 0,  4, 18],
       [54, 20, 32],
       [56, 35,  9]])

>>> result = np.sum(product, axis=1)
array([22, 106, 100])
```

Comment: The matrixes are not square matrixes in most cases, but thank your for your advice!

Comment: @M.Gu I think this still works for non-square matrices.